# Newtonsoft JObject ToString with backslash property

Tags: c#, string, json.net, backslash

I have some data containing a backslash.  For example: `"domain\user"`, which when stored in my variable string is `"domain\\user"`.

I create a `JObject` with a `JProperty` using this variable.

```
JObject root = new JObject();
root.Add(new JProperty("authorizedAccounts", this.AuthorizedAccounts));
```

When I want to use the `JObject` to send it through http request, I use the `ToString` method of `JObject`.

The problem is, my `"domain\\user"` become `"domain\\\\user"`. 
What is the best way to create a Json string from a JObject without modifying backslash? Should I replace `\\` with `\` before or after?

```
string[] authorizedAccounts = new string[] { @"domain\user" };

JObject root = new JObject();
root.Add(new JProperty("authorizedAccounts", authorizedAccounts));
string toSend = root.ToString();
```

[image]

Comment: How does the additional backslash appear in the variable in the first place?  That's probably the best place to tackle this issue, it's probably being escaped there when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Have you actually got an issue - this looks like perhaps you're mixing up debugger info (which will escape an additional level) with what's actually being sent

Comment: I added a code to explain with a simple example.

Comment: You are seeing it in Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: Yes indeed. But my final client is in fact an ElasticSearch index and the first problem is that ElasticSearch display 2 backslash.

When I inspect the root object, it show 2 backslash to my authorizedAccounts. and when I inspect the "tosend", it show 4.

Comment: Your latest screenshot shows it behaving exactly as it should.  A single backslash in the original variable, and two in the (properly escaped) JSON.  The previous doubling up of them was purely the debugger representation of them.  If this is still causing you issues, it must be on the logstash/elastic end of things.

Comment: @JamesThorpe  you are right, I told him that in the answer

Comment: @dufaux , would be nice if you check my answer as correct since it looks you have learnt something new about the debugger , and we did our best to help you. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

[image: See this screenshot]

As you see the debugger scapes the sequences while showing them, but the value remains as it should.

Hope you didn’t lose to much time with that, because your code is working well, no need to do any over engineering  :)

Comment: the "problem" is the backslash in string inside the JObject is already escaped. (it stored as domain\\user).
And when I want to "ToString" the JObject, it escape the both backslash another time. The simple backslash become 4 backslash.

I probably misunderstood something about it but I can't understand how to handle simple backslash in JObject ?

Comment: I added a small code example where 1 backslash become 4 when i want to send a json string.

Comment: @dufaux I only see 2 backslashes